# ActiveRecord Ordering with Sum / Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Going around in circles trying to add ordering to this ActiveRecord statment:

```
sales = Sale.where(supplier_id: params[:id])
            .group(:product_id)
            .limit(params[:limit])
            .sum(:units)
```

sales is an ordered hash that looks like this:

```
{15995=>34, 16068=>128, 14014=>418, 11513=>11, 15528=>6}
```

I'm sure there's something simple i'm missing. Can anyone help please?

EDIT: I should say, I want to order by the sum of units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order before sum:

```
sales = Sale.where(supplier_id: params[:id])
            .group(:product_id)
            .limit(params[:limit])
            .order("SUM(units)")
            .sum(:units)
```